Predicting top N results in multilabel classification when using sk-learn scoring metrics
I am using sk-learn to predict the outcome of a tournament-style bracket, where half the teams are eliminated in each subsequent round. Using the NCAA March Madness basketball tournament as an example, 64 teams start the tournament and  half the teams are eliminated in each subsequent round. I have true labels for every team in a multi-label format: for example, a label of [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] represents a team that was eliminated in the first round, while [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] represents a team that lost in the final game.
I am using RandomizedSearchCV with a pipeline that allows me to test different models independently, as well as a scoring strategy with around 15 different scoring metrics (e.g. f1 score with macro-average scoring, precision with micro-average scoring), to have a variety of results to consider. I have a number of different tournaments to predict, so am using GroupShuffleSplit to split into train-test sets, so results within the same tournaments are not separated.
The current scoring uses the sklearn default where a threshold above 0.5 gives a positive prediction label. However, I would like to change the positive prediction label to represent the highest 2(N0 - n) prediction probabilities for a given tournament, where N0 is the total number of rounds and n is the current round; using the March Madness example, there are 7 rounds until a winner is crowned, so the 8 teams in round 4 with the highest prediction probabilities would have a positive prediction label, regardless of the value of their prediction probabilities.
Given that the tournaments are grouped together during training and evaluation, an added complication is the positive prediction labels would have to be assigned for a given tournament only, so labels are assigned independently for each tournament.
A similar question was asked here, which suggests a way to calculate accuracy for the top N predictions; however, I am using a number of different scoring metrics, so was wondering if there is a way to do this within the current sk-learn scoring metric framework without having to create a number of custom score functions.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
